# Where are ECUs and for which tasks are they used?

Tags: electronic-control-module

ECUs are "Electronic Control Units". I've heard that modern cards have about 30 - 70 ECUs, but I couldn't find good sources for that.

Do you have (citable) sources for where ECUs in modern cars are, how many there are and for what they are used?

Comment: ECU actually refers to *Engine Control Unit*, not Electronic. There are also PCM/PCUs (Powertrain Control Module/Unit) which controls engine/transmission together. There are a multitude of *computers* throughout the vehicle which control different systems. These computers talk on a [CANBus network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus). The computer location is all manufacturer specific as to location. They can be in different places depending on model as well. Due to this, I'm voting to close this question as too broad. There are just *too many answers* for this question.

Comment: @Paulster2 According to [Comprehensive Experimental Analyses of Automotive Attack Surfaces](http://www.autosec.org/pubs/cars-usenixsec2011.pdf) it is "Electronic Control Unit". According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECU), both terms exist and have different meanings.

Comment: An ECU is just an embedded computer. Your car does _not_ have 30-70 of the devices featured in the photo on wikipedia. Most of the time these counts seem to be of every microcontroller in the vehicle (there are a lot of them). I'm sorry, but the answer to this question will probably have to come from academic sources.

Comment: @DavidWinslow The answer I gave comes from an academic source.

Comment: @moose - Well, I guess you have it all figured out. I'd just roll with that then. In their writ they can say what they want to, but with people who actually work on cars, what I've stated is spot on. And remember, academia isn't real life. I've actually read the source you have listed because I was interested in the hack done to the 2014 Jeep.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [Comprehensive Experimental Analyses of Automotive Attack Surfaces](http://www.autosec.org/pubs/cars-usenixsec2011.pdf):

> Charette estimates
>   that a modern luxury vehicle includes up to 70 distinct
>   ECUs including tens of millions of lines of code [5]
>   [...]
>
> [5] R. Charette. This car runs on code. Online: http:
>   //www.spectrum.ieee.org/feb09/7649, Feb.
>   2009.

According to http://spectrum.ieee.org/transportation/systems/this-car-runs-on-code:

> These are impressive amounts of software, yet if you bought a premium-class automobile recently, ”it probably contains close to 100 million lines of software code,” says Manfred Broy, a professor of informatics at Technical University, Munich, and a leading expert on software in cars. All that software executes on 70 to 100 microprocessor-based electronic control units (ECUs) networked throughout the body of your car.
>
> [...]
>
> Even low-end cars now have 30 to 50 ECUs embedded in the body, doors, dash, roof, trunk, seats, and just about anywhere else the car’s designers can think to put them.

Comment: I think my answer means the same without the link, but whatever

Answer (score 3):

**Cars:**

Typically Automotive Electronics/Controllers are usually bunched together into a single unit with multiple micro controllers , with the only exception being the ABS unit or the Chassis electronics(ABS,EBD,TCS,ESP) which might be placed somewhere near the battery or fuse box.

Follow [this](http://www.ecuflash.co/ecu-locations/) link to location of ECUs in most cars.

**Motorcycles**

On motorcycles the ECUs most of the times are placed directly under/inside the seat with the ABS unit again being the exception which is sometimes placed back of the cylinders.

*Note: Every manufacturer and sometimes vehicle has different location for the Automotive Electronics/Controller placement and there is no specific rule for location.*

Comment: Your source seems not to be very good. It also speaks of one ECU, wheres other sources indicate it's rather 30+ ECUs in modern cars.

Comment: As i said, you cannot determine the location of other ECUs for each and every car on the planet. The chassis monitoring system or the infotainment system or the safety system can vary from car to car. Its purely based on ergonomics. however the Engine management system is the one which is frequently opened up so getting a source for that is somewhat possible.

Comment: The ECU is the Engine Control Unit which is one singular unit responsible for controlling the engine.  Other functions such as ABS and ESP may be carried out within this unit or other units within the vehicle.  When people say that a modern car has 30 ECU's, what they actually mean is 30 processing centres, (i.e. computers) but strickly speaking these won't all be controlling the engine (the E in ECU).

Comment: @SteveMatthews You are 100% right, I thought just using the word ECU for the Electronics combined so that will be easier for non car person to grasp the concept.

Comment: @Anarach - You don't have to make it easier. Tell it like it is. If the OP has further questions, answer them. You are talking to the entire community, not to the OP in singular. I'm still debating on voting this as closed for being too broad.

Comment: @Paulster2 Updated answer..

Answer (score 3):

This greatly varies form manufacturer to manufacturer and by what you consider a computer/electronic control unit. For at least the last 20 years cars have been going through the revolution of multiplexing. Let me give you and example. In an old car with power windows big thick wires ran from the drivers door to every other door in the car. When the driver would push the button to roll down a window in the back, the path that the electricity took started from the battery, then went to the drivers door, then back out of the drivers door to the back and finally to the window motor. This makes for very complex wiring, especially in the drivers door (that's not to mention the weight of all that wire).

When cars got more than one computer in them there arose a need to create a network so that these computer could talk to each other (PCM, ABS, air bags for example). Eventually other things started to get connected to the network and the networks grew in size. In modern cars every door has a module in it. When the driver pushes a button to lower the back window, a signal is sent over the network to the back door module over some very skinny wires. The module then activates a relay and lowers the window. Some other things that can be multiplexed, seat controls, steering wheel controls, interior lighting, exterior lighting, smart fuse boxes, navigation systems, entertainment systems, rear hatch controls, the list goes on and on.

If you consider these on network modules "electronic control units" then a car has lots and lots of them. The amount of them and their location is entirely dependent on the manufacturer.